# Using $state.go() with onResume()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to redirect to my login page each time my application comes from background to foreground but I get that error :
**Uncaught TypeError: $state.go is not a function**

So I obviously did something wrong, but I can't get what.

Here is some parts of my code in my app.js :

```
// Ionic Starter App
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

  .state('resetLogin', {
    url: '/resetLogin',
    templateUrl: 'templates/resetLogin.html',
    controller: 'ResetLoginCtrl'
  })
  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })
    .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

})

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $state) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });

  function onDeviceReady() {
  }
});

document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
    function onResume($state){
      $state.go('login');
    }
```

Comment: where is your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juste move your function in the block run and remove $state in the onResume.
Only angular function are injectable. In fact you're probably getting an event object in your case but surely not the $state.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $state) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });

  function onDeviceReady() {
  }
   document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
    function onResume(){
      $state.go('login');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! I thought I've tried this before, but I had to do it the wrong way since it didn't work.
Now it's good :)